# Best practice - Two-way binding web form to editable xml

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ace-editor

I have an ASP.NET MVC app. On one page, I want to update a series of configurations with two options. One is an accordion of little forms to modify an object and the other is two directly edit XML that describes the same object in the form. If the XML changes, I want that shown in the forms comboboxes, radio buttons, etc. If the form changes, I want that to be shown in the XML.

Any recommendations for going about this? My first idea was for every change to the XML, post it to the server, attempt to deserialize it, return it, and update the form from that. However, that pretty much requires a POST for every keyup. I'm fine doing this all client side as well. Is it just easiest to wire up events to every possible form change and give it a corresponding action against the XML. Then everytime the XML changes, parse it and update the form. (I don't think it's possible to see what element was edited, so I'd be updating the whole form everytime.)

I know this is a screwy thing to ask, but this is exactly what my requirements are. Thanks for your input.

Comment: So you are needing to update the file/form without the user clicking a button or submit, right?

Comment: That would be ideal, but I'm flexible there. For the first iteration, I just want two-way binding between a form that describes an XML configuration and the ability to edit that raw XML which, in turn, updates the form.